# Can too much network transfer break a Windows Server 2008 machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine which has been having intermitted networking issues.

After 29 days, 14-ish hours uptime, I find it's not responding to RDP commands again, yet I can access it via terminal (iDRAC)

Wireshark didn't recognise any interface devices, yet I could ping out to network, but by all intents and purposes, the machine was dead to the world.

Then I checked the major network interface.

[image]

The Received bytes counter is literally overflowing the properties panel.

Is this possibly also meaning that the received bytes internally overflowed, causing network issues?

Is there a datatype limit to this value before windows, being the Enterprise(TM) Software(R) it is, falls over? The number I'm seeing here, assuming that it starts with 4,975.. and there are no more numbers in front, is larger than 2^42. Is this a hard limit?

edit: network connectivity is fine after restarting the server. Historically, it hasn't lasted 5 weeks without a reboot over the recent months.

edit: the newer sibling server, which does less traffic, is showing 12 significant figures of traffic, with 8 days uptime. I'd hazard a guess that the first visible digit in the Received Bytes listing (13 visible significant figures) is not the first significant digit in this value.

editedit: my network usage graphs is showing around 2^45 bytes transfer (once converted from megabits), so there's definitely an extra digit before the 4 that we can't see. My estimate from network usage is somewhere in the vicinity of 52 trillion bytes (52,000,000,000,000) over 29 days.

Comment: The limit on the counter (which as John points out can do whatever it wants, Windows doesn't care) is a uint64; it'll roll over after 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. You've got a ways to go. Assuming the above numbers are a representational average, it will take about 30,000 years to roll the counter.

Comment: You can open PowerShell and pop in `gwmi Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface` and it'll dump a bunch of counters including Bytes sent and received.

Comment: Thanks for that data, Chris S. I'm fairly sure windows will have to be restarted for other reasons, and or upgrades, before I hit the counter limit :)

Comment: And/or zombie apocalypse

Comment: Server 2008 has some memory leaks. This is likely your problem, and there are hotfixes to resolve them.

Comment: @ChrisS I wonder where does Windows Server 2012 store this data, or Windows 8.1. As I see, I have "Bytes total" counter on the network connection statistics page, but no counter in that section `Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface` is "total".

Answer (score 6):

The number being displayed will overflow but that won't stop the machine receiving data because the part that does the actual receiving doesn't keep count of the packets. That's just one of those pointless things the OS does for the benefit of us humans. Your RDP issue is unrelated to this. Has that service crashed perhaps?

Comment: Yes, what does `netstat -aon | find ":3389"` tell you?

Comment: I've restarted the machine, going off historical stats for the above. I can check RDP :3389 next time it breaks. RDP and the backup software itself wasn't working, giving errors that the backup clients couldn't be contacted over the network. This happened all about the same time (3:30am this morning)

Comment: @glasnt, what do your system logs tell you about it?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers : not a lot, unfortunately. Application log is clear; System log is just showing Service Control Manager 7036 listings, and one TermDD for the RDP access (occasional encryption failure).